# How can I transform two data frames into another one?

Tags: pandas, indexing, vectorization

I have a `df1` that looks like:

```
             Shady Slim  Eminem
Date                           
2011-01-10   HI     Yes    1500
2011-01-13   HI      No    1500
2011-01-13   BYBY   Yes    4000
2011-01-26   OKDO   Yes    1000
```

I have `df2` that looks like this:

```
              HI     BYBY    OKDO     INT
Date                                                   
2011-01-10  340.99  143.41  614.21     1.0
2011-01-13  344.20  144.55  616.69     1.0
2011-01-13  344.20  144.55  616.69     1.0
2011-01-26  342.38  156.42  616.50     1.0
```

I want to save `Eminem` as Series. I also want each column in `df2` to be a series. I want to multiply `Eminem` by these values in the right corresponding elements of `Shady` and fill up `df3`. 
I want a `df3` that looks like

I also want the `INT` column to be the sum of the rows for each row in `df3`.

I want to this in a vectorization way.

Also, based on the `SLIM` column, if it's `YES` then I want to add the `Eminem * value` else I want the negation of it.

Here are the values I want:

```
              HI     BYBY    OKDO     INT
Date                                                   
2011-01-10  511,485     0     0   sum(row 1)
2011-01-13  -516300   578200  0   sum(row 2)
2011-01-13  0         578200  0   sum(row 3)
2011-01-26  0          0     616500   sum(row 4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**
Use the `pd.DataFrame.mul` method for multiplying and provide an `axis` parameter in order to specify that you want the series you are multiplying by to be lined up along the index.

```
df2.mul(df1.Eminem, axis=0)

                   HI      BYBY       OKDO      SOME      COOL     INT
Date                                                                  
2011-01-10   511485.0  215115.0   921315.0  108030.0  184785.0  1500.0
2011-01-13   516300.0  216825.0   925035.0  110310.0  186810.0  1500.0
2011-01-13  1376800.0  578200.0  2466760.0  294160.0  498160.0  4000.0
2011-01-26   342380.0  156420.0   616500.0   76370.0  125800.0  1000.0
```

---

**Option 2**
If by chance, the series in which you are trying to multiply by is already ordered in the way you'd like to multiply, you can forgo the index and access the `values` attribute.

```
df2.mul(df1.Eminem.values, 0)

                   HI      BYBY       OKDO      SOME      COOL     INT
Date                                                                  
2011-01-10   511485.0  215115.0   921315.0  108030.0  184785.0  1500.0
2011-01-13   516300.0  216825.0   925035.0  110310.0  186810.0  1500.0
2011-01-13  1376800.0  578200.0  2466760.0  294160.0  498160.0  4000.0
2011-01-26   342380.0  156420.0   616500.0   76370.0  125800.0  1000.0
```

---

**Option 3**
If index proves difficult, you can append a level that makes it unique

```
unique_me = lambda d: d.set_index(d.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True)
df2.pipe(unique_me).mul(df1.pipe(unique_me).Eminem, axis=0).reset_index(-1, drop=True)

                   HI      BYBY       OKDO      SOME      COOL     INT
Date                                                                  
2011-01-10   511485.0  215115.0   921315.0  108030.0  184785.0  1500.0
2011-01-13   516300.0  216825.0   925035.0  110310.0  186810.0  1500.0
2011-01-13  1376800.0  578200.0  2466760.0  294160.0  498160.0  4000.0
2011-01-26   342380.0  156420.0   616500.0   76370.0  125800.0  1000.0
```

---

**With Slim Factor**

```
df2.drop('INT', axis=1, errors='ignore').mul(df1.Eminem.values, 0).assign(
    INT=lambda d: (lambda s: s.mask(df1.Slim.eq('No'), -s))(d.sum(1)))

                   HI      BYBY       OKDO      SOME      COOL        INT
Date                                                                     
2011-01-10   511485.0  215115.0   921315.0  108030.0  184785.0  1940730.0
2011-01-13   516300.0  216825.0   925035.0  110310.0  186810.0 -1955280.0
2011-01-13  1376800.0  578200.0  2466760.0  294160.0  498160.0  5214080.0
2011-01-26   342380.0  156420.0   616500.0   76370.0  125800.0  1317470.0
```

Comment: One Last thing is the `Slim` factor.

Comment: The numbers are all correct except for `INT`. For int, if it's a `NO`, I want the negation of the sum of the other elements in that row. Otherwise I want it to be the positive sum of the rows.

Comment: I gave an example of what I needed.